# Emacs lisp: Generate compiler warnings

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, compiler-warnings

Byte compiling emacs lisp is pretty useful, as it generates compiler warnings that, though sometimes cryptic, always point at an error or unfinished tasks, such as missing imports or unimplemented functions.

However, I cannot find a way to generate *custom* compiler-warnings that integrate well with the `*Compile-Log*` buffer, i.e. that show the position of the error like

```
mymodule.el:247:1:Warning: Unused lexical variable `file-name'
```

E.g. I'm using the subsequent code for placing todo items that raise compile-time messages:

```
(eval-when-compile 
  (defmacro TODO (string)
    `(eval-when-compile 
       (message "TODO: %s" ,string))))
```

However, I cannot find a way to add information (at compile-time) on

- file name
- line-number

At load-time the variable `load-file-name` is available, but it is `nil` at compile-time. The variable `default-directory` is defined at compile-time but doesn't help in this case.

For the line-number I know no method at all.

When using `(warn ...)` instead, I get something like

```
Warning (emacs): TODO: Complete or remove
```

i.e. no position information at all. If I use `(error ...)`, I get the line number etc displayed automatically, but compilation stops instead of showing *all* errors and warnings, so it is not a viable solution either.

#### Update

A partial solution seems to be

```
(funcall (if byte-compile-current-file 'byte-compile-warn 'warn) FORMAT [ARGS ...])
```

Comment: `load-file-name` is not set at compile-time though. As for `cl-declare`, it doesn't seem to provide facilities for creating new warnings. Only for controlling existing warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the internal variables `byte-compile-current-file` (the name of the file being compiled) and `byte-compile-read-position` (the character position at the start of the last `read`).

Alternatively, you can try the function `byte-compile-warning-prefix` which *inserts*  the `file:line` prefix in the `*Warnings*` buffer.

Either way, you are on your own, messing with the Emacs internals; SO is your only friend. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that was a problem.  And even `byte-compile-read-position` is fairly poor because it's not yet up-to-date when the macro is expanded.  In Emacs's trunk there is `macroexp--warn-and-return`, tho as the `--` implies, it's currently still considered internal.  E.g.

```
(defmacro TODO (string)
  (macroexp--warn-and-return
    (format "TODO: %s" string)
    nil))
```

To understand how to use it, you have to understand that it works by returning a special piece of code which makes the byte-compiler later on (when the line-info is available) emit the message.